# Cannot access onedrive details for another user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While the endpoint works fine to get details of my own OneDrive I am having trouble using Microsoft Graph to get the status of another user's OneDrive. i.e. Do they have one, have they added any files.

First, I create a new user account.

Then, using Microsoft Graph Explorer I log in as myself, (an administrator) and I request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive
```

This returns

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "User's mysite not found.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "6c2f1d09-ebb1-49fe-83ac-46caf946eefa",
        "date": "2017-11-02T17:55:45"
    }
}
```

}

If I then log in as the user and access her OneDrive via the web and retry the same endpoint it returns:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "aecda4bb-4baf-42ab-81f0-ce9e3b959dd8",
        "date": "2017-11-02T17:59:41"
    }
}
```

}

Shouldn't it return the id of the drive here instead? I am requesting all permissions when signing in via Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How long after you created the OneDrive did you attempt this call? It may take a little time to propagate.

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur - I've tried it immediately after and 3 days after with the same result. :(

Comment: Very strange. Are you able to upload a file to the user's OneDrive using the web interface? Also, are you able to get anything back when you request `GET /users/{userId}/drives`?

Comment: Yes I can upload files to the user's OneDrive using the web interface. Note that I cannot get the drive details of any other users, not just this one. Using `GET/users/{userId}/drives` returns `{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": []
}`

Comment: Normally I would expect you to get a `403` if you don't have permission but just in case, can you confirm that you have requested `Files.Read.All` scope and have received Admin Consent?

Comment: I have the same issue and can confirm that the account I used has the required rights. When I use an application token to do the same request in a C# application, it does work. But the auto-provisioning does not work (which results in the "User's mysite not found." error).

Comment: Files.Read.All is selected. I am an Admin. I've also given Admin consent to use Graph to the whole organisation but it still returns the same message.