# OneDrive not provisioning

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to create an account for a user, and provision it with OneDrive. The application has all the required rights, and the user has a license which includes OneDrive for Business.

When using `/v1.0/users/username/drive` endpoint from Microsoft Graph to provision the OneDrive, as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_get#get-a-users-onedrive) under 'Get a user's OneDrive', the following error presents itself:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "User's mysite not found.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "996c75c0-19d5-416e-8070-e9af593ae1d7",
        "date": "2017-11-08T08:23:22"
        }
    }
}
```

The OneDrive doesn't get provisioned, not even if I check after some time. When I go to provision it manually by logging into OneDrive for the user however, it does.

So my question is; **why doesn't the user's OneDrive get provisioned?**

---

*Found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081881/cannot-access-onedrive-details-for-another-user) just now.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_get):

> If a user's OneDrive is not provisioned but the user has a license to use OneDrive, this request will automatically provision the user's drive, when using delegated authentication.

The key bit here being "delegated authentication". This is stating that the API will only provision a `Drive` when there is a `user` in context. In other words, your app must be using either the `authorization_code` or `implicit` OAUTH grant for automatic provisioning to be triggered.

If you're using "application authentication" (i.e. the `client_credentials` grant), automatic provisioning won't be triggered.

Comment: But what about this in the documentation (link in the original question)? 

"If a user's OneDrive is not provisioned but the user has a license to use OneDrive, this request will automatically provision the user's drive, when using delegated authentication."

Comment: Is the {user-id} your passing the same as the user who is authenticated for that session?

Comment: No it's an registered application with a token.